# Работа с датой

Tags: php

Надо узнать, сколько *секунд, минут, часов, дней* осталось до переменной $metka

Чтобы отображалось, например: 10 дней 5 часов 24 минуты 5 секунд

```
$metka= mktime(19, 0, 0 ,5 , 11, 2012);
$day=time();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getTimeLeft($point, $format = '#d дней, #h, часов, #m мин, #s сек') {
  $left_tstamp = $point - time();
  $left = array();
  $left['d'] = floor($left_tstamp / 86400);
  $left_tstamp -= $left['d'] * 86400;
  $left['h'] = floor($left_tstamp / 3600);
  $left_tstamp -= $left['h'] * 3600;
  $left['m'] = floor($left_tstamp / 60);
  $left_tstamp -= $left['m'] * 60;
  $left['s'] = $left_tstamp;
  $result = $format;
  foreach($left as $c => $v)
    $result = str_replace('#'.$c, $v, $result);
  return $result;
  }
```

Что-то вроде того. Должно работать.

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще))).

```
$metka = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y G:i:s','11.05.2012 19:00:00');
$now = new DateTime;

$diff = $now->diff($metka);

echo $diff->format('Осталось %a дней %h часов %i минут %s секунд');
```

Comment: *php5.2.0+, а так да, не уследил я, каюсь.

Comment: судя по документации php 5.3.0+